# Mostrar na página o total de id's registrados no BD

Tags: php, sql

Existe uma tabela que mostra todos os registros do BD, porém numa página do meu projeto onde deveria mostrar o total de registro(id) da minha tabela.

Arquivo de conexão:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "house863_teste", "teste", "house863_registro");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Falha ao conectar com o mysql: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}?>
```

Arquivo que traz os dados pra tabela HTML:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM lista ";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$x=1;   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo("
<tr>
    <td class=\"n\">".$row['id']."</td>
    <td class=\"nm\">".$row['nome']."</td>
    <td><span class=\"cont\" id=\"s".$x."\" inicial=\"".$row['tempo']."\"></span></td>
    <td class=\"qp\">".$row['pm']."</td>
    <td class=\"sm\">".$row['dific']."</td>
    <td class=\"op\">".$row['op']."</td>
    <td class=\"btnt\"><button class=\"btn1\" onclick=\"dispara('s".$x."')\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"".$row['link']."\">Clique aqui</a></button></td>
</tr>");
$x=$x+1;   
}

echo("</tbody>");
?>
```

Depois de fazer a conexão, como eu posso mostrar na página o total de `id`'s registrados?

Exemplo html:

```
Total de registros(<?php require_once("total.php");?>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia trazer na própria consulta

```
<?php 
require_once("config.php");
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM lista ";
$total = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
```

A função count já traz o número de registros da tabela.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM lista ";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

O código acima pega o numero de linhas da query `$result` e joga dentro da variável `total`.

```
echo $total;
$x=1;   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo("
<tr>
    <td class=\"n\">".$row['id']."</td>
    <td class=\"nm\">".$row['nome']."</td>
    <td><span class=\"cont\" id=\"s".$x."\" inicial=\"".$row['tempo']."\"></span></td>
    <td class=\"qp\">".$row['pm']."</td>
    <td class=\"sm\">".$row['dific']."</td>
    <td class=\"op\">".$row['op']."</td>
    <td class=\"btnt\"><button class=\"btn1\" onclick=\"dispara('s".$x."')\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"".$row['link']."\">Clique aqui</a></button></td>
</tr>");
$x=$x+1;   
}

echo("</tbody>");
?>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o código?

Comment: Claro, mysqli_num_rows($result); ira retornar o numero de linhas da query "$result", esse numero vai ser jogado dentro da variável "$total" e o comando <?php echo $total ?> ira escrever na tele o numero.

Comment: Leone edita e coloca na resposta.